why does an inner viewBox changes my scale?
In a nutshell:
In this simplified example, I don't understand why my third cross is smaller than the others, I would have expected all cross to be the same


<svg width="512" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<!-- My baseline: no viewbox, and I use percentages -->
<svg x="0%" width="25%" height="100%">
        <line x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100%" stroke="black" stroke-width="5%"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" stroke="black" stroke-width="5%"/>
</svg>

<!-- With a viewbox, to be able to not use percentages but still have something independant from my viewport -->
<svg x="25%" width="25%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>

<!-- with a viewbox one level below. Why is this cross smaller? -->
<svg x="50%" width="25%" height="100%">
    <g viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
    </g>
</svg>

<!-- with a viewbox inside a viewbox. The size is restored by I have no clue why... -->
<svg x="75%" width="25%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <g viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="50" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
    </g>
</svg>
</svg>




More context

Why I expect all crosses to be the same:

The first one is my baseline
The second one uses non percent coordinates, but given the dimensions of the viewBox it should be the same (which is the case)
The third one is the same as the second one, except that the viewBox is defined one level below. But the viewport and the viewBox are still the same so I don't expect any change (but I'm wrong)
I don't understand the fourth one. I've noticed that I get back my cross when I repeat my viewBox directive, but I have no clue why.


The full context of my question is that I'm trying to create a tilesheet. It contains an element with different rotations, so I define this elements in a <defs> and then apply some transform on it, in successive sub-svg. I define this element with a viewBox because it's the only way I'm aware of, to be able to use a <path> while still being independent of the viewPort. But I've noticed this behavior where some of my tiles have an unexpected scale. (my example above has no <defs> and no <path> because I managed to get a simpler example than with my original svg)



That viewBox on you <g> Group element is ignored
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox
viewBox is only valid on elements:

SVG
MARKER
PATTERN
SYMBOL
VIEW


For a tile game a native Web Component with SVG only for one tile might be easier.
All positioning is done with HTML and CSS


<tiles style="display:grid;grid:repeat(3,1fr)/repeat(3,1fr);background:teal;width:240px">
  <svg-tile></svg-tile>  <svg-tile></svg-tile>            <svg-tile></svg-tile>
  <svg-tile></svg-tile>  <svg-tile rotate=0></svg-tile>   <svg-tile></svg-tile>
  <svg-tile></svg-tile>  <svg-tile></svg-tile>            <svg-tile></svg-tile>
</tiles>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-tile", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
      super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
        .append(
          createElement("style", {
            innerHTML: `svg {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}` +
                       `path {stroke:black}`
          }),
          this.rotation = createElement("style"), // set by rotate(x)
          createElement("div", {
            innerHTML: `<svg viewBox="0 0 6 6"><path d="M3 0v6M0 3h6"/></svg>`
          })
        );
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.rotate = ~~(this.getAttribute("rotate") || 45);
      this.onclick = (evt) => this.rotate = this._rotate + 45;
    }
    set rotate(value) {
      this.rotation.innerHTML = `svg{transform:rotate(${this._rotate=value}deg)}`;
    }
  })
</script>



